# Difference between createOrReplaceTempView and registerTempTable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am new to spark and was trying out a few commands in `sparkSql` using python when I came across these two commands:

[createOrReplaceTempView](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView)() and [registerTempTable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.registerTempTable)().

What is the difference between the two commands?. They seem to have same set of functionalities.

Answer (score 36):

`registerTempTable` is a part of the 1.x API and has been deprecated in Spark 2.0.

`createOrReplaceTempView` and `createTempView` have been introduced in Spark 2.0, as a replacement for `registerTempTable`.

Other than that `registerTempTable` and `createOrReplaceTempView`  functionally equivalent and the former one calls the latter one.

Answer (score 15):

No difference at all between createOrReplaceTempView and registerTempTable both performs the same functionality and if you open the below link and search for registerTempTable you can see that this function is deprecated in 2.0.

There is a note like below:
Deprecated in 2.0 use createOrReplaceTempView instead.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: Is it different than other two questions ?

Comment: other two answers you mean, answer is no. When I click the question to answer at that time its unanswered.

Answer (score 7):

Both the function between `createOrReplaceTempView` and `registerTempTable` are same and have same functionalities.

However `registerTempTable` is depricated from spark 2.0.0

Instead of `registerTempTable`, `createOrReplaceTempView` is used

> ```
> @deprecated("Use createOrReplaceTempView(viewName) instead.", "2.0.0")
>   def registerTempTable(tableName: String): Unit = {
>     createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
>   }
> ```