# How to extract Azure Application Insights Events using Pyspark?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pyspark, azure-application-insights, azure-databricks

I'm trying to capture Azure Application Insights event in structured format using the below code in Pyspark (Azure Databricks) -

```
import requests
import json

appId = "..."
appKey = "..."

query = """traces | where timestamp > ago(1d) | order by timestamp"""
params = {"query": query}
headers = {'X-Api-Key': appKey}
url = f'https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
logs = json.loads(response.text)

json = json.dumps(logs)

jsonRDD = sc.parallelize([json])
df = spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(jsonRDD)

display(df)
```

However, for some reason, this is returning json structure only. How to convert this into the structured or tabular format ?

Please help!

Comment: I tried doing it in a different way and it worked. 
Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You can also post it as an answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 1):

`registerTempTable` has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145866/difference-between-createorreplacetempview-and-registertemptable) in spark 2.0. Use `createOrReplaceTempView` instead.

```
df = spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(jsonRDD)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
query= spark.sql("SELECT timestamp FROM traces)
```

PySpark SQL also provides a way to read a JSON file by creating a temporary view directly from the reading file using `spark.sql(“load JSON to temporary view”)`

```
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW zipcode USING json OPTIONS" + 
      " (path 'resources/zipcodes.json')")
spark.sql("select * from zipcode").show()
```

You can refer to [How to parse nested JSON objects in spark sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948789/how-to-parse-nested-json-objects-in-spark-sql) and [PySpark Read JSON file into DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-json-file-into-dataframe/)